# local cluster: error trying to connect: record overflow

Tags: rpc

I was working on my local cluster, and all of a sudden i get the following error:

Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (https://localhost:8899/): error trying to connect: record overflow

whenever i interact with the cluster (solana balance, deploying contract etc.). Deleting the ledger and restarting my computer doesnt help. Any ideas?

Comment: by "local cluster" do you mean `solana-test-validator` or some other validator setup?

Answer (score 1):

The builtin RPC service doesn't support HTTPS.  This is typically implemented via a proxy. Try http://localhost:8899